# Javac illegal expression error?

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java and have been trying to figure out why javac keeps giving me an error while trying to run it. I am really stumped and do not understand my error. This is the code that is appearing in the error message, it is apart of a modification for a game.

```
public static LOTRFaction forName(String name)
  {
    for (LOTRFaction f : ) {
      if (f.codeName().equals(name)) {
        return f;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static LOTRFaction forID(int ID)
  {
    for (LOTRFaction f : ) {
      if (f.ordinal() == ID) {
        return f;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: `for (LOTRFaction f : ???) {` - replace ??? with whatever array/Collection you wish to iterate over.

Comment: you are missing something inside your for loops

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there appears to be no evidence of research.  Please [edit] your question to show what research you have done.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a syntax error is you are missing a piece of your [`Enhanced for loop`](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/480-the-enhanced-for-loop.html). An enhanced for loop requires the following syntax:

```
for (Object my_object : my_object_iterable) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Where `my_object` is assigned to each value in `my_object_iterable` one at a time. It is much like python's for loops using the `in` keyword. `my_object_iterable` must be an iterable object (Array, List, ArrayList, etc.) and contain the same type of my_object. You had a for loop with no iterable! The java compiler had no idea what you wanted to loop over because you didn't supply anything to do so.